# read parametrized string from properties file with further execution using PreparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc, string-concatenation

i have a quick question.

I have parametrized SQL statement in a property file like this

```
update = update table1 set value = 5 where ids in (?)
```

And I have a string in my class which is

```
String test = "1, 2, 3, 4"
```

I need to read the property file, add the parameter which is ? and finally execute the PreparedStatement, but I can figure out how can I concatenate the string from the properties file with my test string to finally pass the following query to be executed;

```
update table1 set value = 'blablabla';
```

I have written like this but it is not really working:

```
String pstring = prop.getProperty(update);
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(pstring);
pstmt.setString(1, test);
pstmt.executeUpdate(pstmt);
```

The following stack trace is being thrown:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:395)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:802)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:205)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1008)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1307)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3449)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3530)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1350)
```

I’d really appreciate if you could help me as I’m new in java and i was not able to figure it out yet.

Thanks

Comment: Is your code throwing an exception?  What is happening?

Comment: This is the exception that i receive , updated in the initial post

Answer (score 2):

[`load`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29) returns a `void` type. You need to load the properties first before you can retrieve the query `String`

```
prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
String queryString = prop.getProperty("update");
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(queryString);
...
```

Comment: My bad, i should have posted like you wrote. My code is actually says the same thing, but still its not working. If i had only that string to be loaded from the properties file it should have been fine, but it is parametrized as i explained in the first place.

Comment: your stacktrace indicates that the field `value` is a numeric field but you're passing in a text type. Read [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_01722_invalid_number.htm)

Comment: Of note is that since 1.6, `Properties` has a `.load()` method accepting a `Reader` as an argument. Which means you don't have to write in ISO anymore...